# FDCAN peripheral sends only partial CAN frame with no data

Tags: stm32, can-bus, corrupt

I'm trying to get the FDCAN peripheral (on an stm32h750) to talk on a standard 1mbps CAN network.  I'm sending a test message, defined here:

```
FDCAN_TxHeaderTypeDef txheader;

txheader.Identifier = 69;

txheader.IdType = FDCAN_STANDARD_ID;
txheader.TxFrameType = FDCAN_DATA_FRAME;

txheader.DataLength = FDCAN_DLC_BYTES_8;
txheader.BitRateSwitch = FDCAN_BRS_OFF;
txheader.FDFormat = FDCAN_CLASSIC_CAN;
txheader.TxEventFifoControl = FDCAN_NO_TX_EVENTS;
txheader.MessageMarker = 0;

testdata[0] = 'b';
testdata[1] = 'l';
testdata[2] = 'a';
testdata[3] = 'r';
testdata[4] = 'g';
testdata[5] = 'f';
testdata[6] = 'o';
testdata[7] = 'o';
HAL_FDCAN_AddMessageToTxFifoQ(&hfdcan1, &txheader, testdata);
```

and I've attached a logic analyzer capture of the bus to show the result.  [image: logic analyzer capture]

Any thoughts on where to look?  I'm not sure what could cause this symptom.  The peripheral appears to be able to read to an existing (correctly formatted frame)

Here is my fdcan initialization code:

```
  hfdcan1.Instance = FDCAN1;
  hfdcan1.Init.FrameFormat = FDCAN_FRAME_CLASSIC;
  hfdcan1.Init.Mode = FDCAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hfdcan1.Init.AutoRetransmission = ENABLE;
  hfdcan1.Init.TransmitPause = DISABLE;
  hfdcan1.Init.ProtocolException = DISABLE;
  hfdcan1.Init.NominalPrescaler = 20;
  hfdcan1.Init.NominalSyncJumpWidth = 1;
  hfdcan1.Init.NominalTimeSeg1 = 5;
  hfdcan1.Init.NominalTimeSeg2 = 4;
  hfdcan1.Init.DataPrescaler = 20;
  hfdcan1.Init.DataSyncJumpWidth = 1;
  hfdcan1.Init.DataTimeSeg1 = 5;
  hfdcan1.Init.DataTimeSeg2 = 4;
  hfdcan1.Init.MessageRAMOffset     = 0;
  hfdcan1.Init.StdFiltersNbr        = 1;
  hfdcan1.Init.ExtFiltersNbr        = 0;
  hfdcan1.Init.RxFifo0ElmtsNbr      = 2;
  hfdcan1.Init.RxFifo0ElmtSize      = FDCAN_DATA_BYTES_64;
  hfdcan1.Init.RxFifo1ElmtsNbr      = 0;
  hfdcan1.Init.RxBuffersNbr         = 64;
  hfdcan1.Init.TxEventsNbr          = 0;
  hfdcan1.Init.TxBuffersNbr         = 64;
  hfdcan1.Init.TxFifoQueueElmtsNbr  = 2;
  hfdcan1.Init.TxFifoQueueMode      = FDCAN_TX_FIFO_OPERATION;
  hfdcan1.Init.TxElmtSize           = FDCAN_DATA_BYTES_64;
  if (HAL_FDCAN_Init(&hfdcan1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
```

I have tried:
-messing with DLC to be the number 8 instead of FDCAN_DLC_BYTES_8 which expands to 0x00080000U as well as FDCAN_DATA_BYTES_8 which expands to 4.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by making `FDCAN_TxHeaderTypeDef txheader;` global rather than a local variable.

Comment: This implies that you should have `memset()` the structure to zero when it was a local variable. The scope doesn't fix it - the fact that global variables are implicitly zeroed, and local variables are not, is the answer. Seems like there are other fields in the structure that you are not setting, and so have garbage values on the stack.